# Regular expression in perl for getting text between 1. and 2

Tags: regex, perl

```
1) some text 2)
1. some text 2.
1) some text 2.


1. 2.10.10.20 some text 2.
1) 2.10.10.20 2)
```

i want to get the text between 1) and 2) or 1. or 2. ,

here is what i have written

```
1[).](.*?)2[).]
```

so here in perl $1 will give me the text between , but this will fail in the third match ( `1. 2.10.10.20 some text 2.` )

so can some one please help me in setting up the regexp.

Comment: As a first remark, you don't need the pipe `|` in your character classes.

Comment: thanks , i have removed |

Comment: So, does it fail because it catches `1. 2.10.10.20 some text 2.` or because it should?

Comment: it will get nothing coz, this will try to get the text between 1. and 2. and here in this case it will match 1. and after that i have 2. in the IP address ..and so if i have `1. ab 2.10.10.20 some text 2.` this regexp will match `ab` but i want `ab 2.10.20.20 some text`

Comment: You probably don't want a minimal match in this case (loose the ?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ m{ 1[.)] \s (.+?) \s 2[.)] }x) {
        say qq{'$1'};
    }
}

__DATA__
1) some text 2)
1. some text 2.
1) some text 2.


1. 2.10.10.20 some text 2.
1) 2.10.10.20 2)
```

Output:

```
'some text'
'some text'
'some text'
'2.10.10.20 some text'
'2.10.10.20'
```

Comment: thanks Sinan , it worked. i have one more question if i want to make `\s` optional.. means `1)some text2)` and `1) some text 2)` i want to match both.

Comment: i think i got it `($line =~ m{ [12][.)] \s? (.+?) \s? [12][.)] }x)`

Comment: @Tanuj I think you should go greedy. If you use `\s?`, you will fail to match something like `1) 2.12.10.20 2)`. Use this instead: ` m/ 1[).] \s? (.+) \s? 2[).] /x;`

Comment: thanks for the help @imran , but i didn't get the difference between `.+` and `.+?`

Comment: @Tanuj compare the regex `m{ [12][.)] \s? (.+?) \s? [12][.)] }x` with the regex `m{ [12][.)] \s? (.+) \s? [12][.)] }x` when run with the input line `1) 2.12.10.20 2)`

Comment: @imram , i think `.+?` is more accurate. this `.+` will fail in the below scenario ` 1. some text 2.10.10.20 2. some text 3. some test 2.10.20.20 `  as it will  match `some text 2.10.10.20 2. some text 3. some test `

Comment: @tanuj Clearly the regex will need more work to account for varying input. Is this scenario conceivable: `1) 2.12.10.20 2)`? Will your regex match it properly?

Comment: @imran no it didn't work :-( But when i am using `.+` it's getting fail here ` 1) 2.10.10.20 some text 2) some text 3) 2.10.10.20 `

Comment: @Tanuj are you sure `m{ [12][.)] \s? (.+?) \s? [12][.)] }x` works as expected with `1) 2.12.10.20 2)`? It didn't work for me.

Comment: so when i am using `.+?` it's getting failed  here `1) 2.12.10.20 2) ` and when i am using `.+` its getting failed here `1. 2.10.10.20forth 2. nothingf 3. dfadfad 4. dfd 2.10` it will match `2.10.10.20forth 2. nothingf 3. dfadfad 4. dfd`  so can we match for some [a-z] after 1) or 1.

Comment: @imran any suggestion on the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make your regex greedy:

```
m/1[).](.*)2[).]/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like:

```
 $line=~/^1[).]\s?([^\s].*[^\s])\s?2[).]$/
```